# Programmatically send SMS in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to send SMS programmatically in Windows Phone 8? I've looked around a bit, and to my surprice, didn't find anything... :s

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please see the tutorial in the following link

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/How-to-compose-and-send-SMS-from-Windows-Phone-apps

This should help. Please note to finally send a SMS user interaction is a Must, you can not automate that. The user must tap on send SMS button

full code

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using PhoneApp1.Resources;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

namespace PhoneApp1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();

            smsComposeTask.To = _Number.Text;
            smsComposeTask.Body = _Message.Text;
            smsComposeTask.Show();
        }

        // Sample code for building a localized ApplicationBar
        //private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
        //{
        //    // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.
        //    ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

        //    // Create a new button and set the text value to the localized string from AppResources.
        //    ApplicationBarIconButton appBarButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/appbar.add.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
        //    appBarButton.Text = AppResources.AppBarButtonText;
        //    ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(appBarButton);

        //    // Create a new menu item with the localized string from AppResources.
        //    ApplicationBarMenuItem appBarMenuItem = new ApplicationBarMenuItem(AppResources.AppBarMenuItemText);
        //    ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(appBarMenuItem);
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try and send more than 140 characters in the body?

Comment: @Beanwah Never tried that, but since its is being directly handled by Task provided by default there should be no issue

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation : [How to use the SMS compose task for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394005%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To be more clear use this function

```
//---sends an SMS message to another device---
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();
    smsComposeTask.To = phoneNumber;
    smsComposeTask.Body = message;
    smsComposeTask.Show();
}
```